# Display the other page content to Index.html page without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

Can anyone tell me the code to display the other page content in index page without refresh when click on anchor tag. All the pages are in HTML. Second page content can be shown with slide.

I want the code for HTML files not for PHP.

page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#menu > a").click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault(); 
        /*  
        if uncomment the above line, html5 nonsupported browers won't change the url but will display the ajax content;
        if commented, html5 nonsupported browers will reload the page to the specified link. 
        */

        //get the link location that was clicked
        pageurl = $(this).attr("href");

        //to get the ajax content and display in div with id 'content'
        $.ajax({url:pageurl,success: function(data){
            $("#content").html(data);
        }});

        //to change the browser URL to 'pageurl'
        if(pageurl!=window.location){
            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},"",pageurl);    
        }
        return false;  
    });
});

/* the below code is to override back button to get the ajax content without reload*/
$(window).bind("popstate", function() {
    $.ajax({url:location.pathname,success: function(data){
        $("#content").html(data);
    }});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="menu">
    <a href="test2.html" id="ab">menu1</a> 
</div>

<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Secondpage.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="content">Second page</div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the FAQ for guidelines on how to ask a question. We cannot just do all your work, please be more specific.

Comment: hope this is what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/2dz29qnq/

Comment: No actually i have tried but it is not working

Comment: So why dont you show us what you have tried so far? Maybe we can push you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Use a so called 'Master page'. In there define the placeholder for the content:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <title>Untitled Document</title>
     <script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="menu">
          <a href="SecondPage.html" id="ab">menu1</a> 
      </div>

      <div id="content"><!-- Where your pages get injected --></div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Then your 'partial pages' need to be injected in the content div. This means your other pages do not need to be whole html pages, only the parts you want to inject there:

SecondPage.html:

```
<div>
    <!-- your page 2 content, without the <html>, <head> and <body> tags -->
    lorem ipsum
</div>
```

script:

```
$(function(){
    $("#menu > a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        //get the link location that was clicked
        pageurl = $(this).attr("href");

        //to get the ajax content and display in div with id 'content'
        $.ajax({url:pageurl,success: function(data){
            $("#content").html(data);
        }});

        // Or, even more simpler:
        // $("#content").load(pageurl);

        //to change the browser URL to 'pageurl'
        if(pageurl!=window.location){
            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},"",pageurl);    
        }
        return false;  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your main page write this code

```
<script>

    $('#content_holder').load('secondpage.html');

</script>
```

Comment: But i want to show the content when click on <a> tag. and want to hide previous page content

Answer (score 0):

using jquery it can be possible to use content from another page in html. Follow these below code here:

1. create a two any file index.html and Secondpage.html
   In index.html paste below code : -

   $(function(){
       $( "#target" ).click(function() {
     $("#content_holder").load("Secondpage.html"); 
      });
   });

   2. Put below code inside body tag and click at click me
      Click Me